# How to group_by when there is null values R?

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by

Lets say I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3),
  result = c(NA, 33, 13, 44, 23, 44, 52, 11, NA, NA),
  flag = c("", "", "Y", "", "Y", "", "", "", "", ""),
  col_1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d" , "e" , "f" , "g" , "h", "i", "j")
)
```

Outcome:

```
   id  result  flag   col_1
1   1     NA           a
2   1     33           b
3   1     13    Y      c
4   1     44           d
5   2     23    Y      e
6   2     44           f
7   2     52           g
8   2     11           h
9   3     NA           i
10  3     NA           j
```

Each unique "**id**" has a **base value**. The base value for each unique "id" is equal to the "**value**" when "**flag**" is equal to "**Y**".

I want to create a new column named "**base_vale**" that stores the base value for each unique "id" and then calculate a new column named percentage change. The final outcome looks like as follow:

```
   id   result   flag col_1  base_value  percentage_change
3   1     NA          a         13        NA
4   1     33          b         13        153.846154
1   1     13    Y     c         13        0.000000
2   1     44          d         13        238.461538
7   2     23    Y     e         23        0.000000
8   2     44          f         23        91.304348
5   2     52          g         23        126.086957
6   2     11          h         23        -52.173913
9   3     NA          i         NA        NA
10  3     NA          j         NA        NA
```

The code I am using now is as follow:

```
df_right <- df[df$flag == "Y", ]
df <- merge(x = df,
            y = df_right,
            by = "id",
            all.x = TRUE)
df <- df %>% rename(
  flag = flag.x,
  result = result.x,
  base_value = result.y,
  col_1 = col_1.x
)
df <- subset(df, select = -c(flag.y, col_1.y))
df$percentage_change <-
  (df$result - df$base_value) / df$base_value * 100
df <- df[order(df$col_1), ]
```

Another potential solution could be the following code if I didn't have NA values in result. So the following code doesn't word:

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(base_value = result[which(flag == "Y")] ,
         percentage_change = (result - base_value)/base_value * 100) %>%
  ungroup()
```

I am not happy with my solution and am looking for a cleaner and nicer code to get the job done. Anny help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `ifelse` to check if there are any `Y`s in the group, and set `NA` otherwise:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    base_value = ifelse(any(flag == "Y"), result[flag == "Y"], NA),
    percentage_change = (result - base_value)/base_value * 100
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 10 × 6
#       id result flag  col_1 base_value percentage_change
#    <int>  <int> <chr> <chr>      <int>             <dbl>
#  1     1     NA ""    a             13              NA  
#  2     1     33 ""    b             13             154. 
#  3     1     13 "Y"   c             13               0  
#  4     1     44 ""    d             13             238. 
#  5     2     23 "Y"   e             23               0  
#  6     2     44 ""    f             23              91.3
#  7     2     52 ""    g             23             126. 
#  8     2     11 ""    h             23             -52.2
#  9     3     NA ""    i             NA              NA  
# 10     3     NA ""    j             NA              NA
```

Also please note that empty strings `""` are different from missing values `NA` are different from `NULL` values (don't exist, length 0, can't really be in data frames).

---

Using this data:

```
df = read.table(text = "   id  result  flag   col_1
1   1     NA    ''       a
2   1     33    ''       b
3   1     13    Y      c
4   1     44    ''       d
5   2     23    Y      e
6   2     44    ''       f
7   2     52    ''       g
8   2     11    ''       h
9   3     NA    ''       i
10  3     NA    ''       j", header = T)
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different approach in defining the base value. The formula from @Gregor Thomas:

```
library(dplyr)

df  %>%  
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(flag, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(base_value = last(result),
         percent_change = (result - base_value)/base_value * 100)

     id result flag  col_1 base_value percent_change
   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> <chr>      <dbl>          <dbl>
 1     1     NA ""    a             13           NA  
 2     1     33 ""    b             13          154. 
 3     1     44 ""    d             13          238. 
 4     1     13 "Y"   c             13            0  
 5     2     44 ""    f             23           91.3
 6     2     52 ""    g             23          126. 
 7     2     11 ""    h             23          -52.2
 8     2     23 "Y"   e             23            0  
 9     3     NA ""    i             NA           NA  
10     3     NA ""    j             NA           NA
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be also done by extraction on the first `[1]` element i.e. if there are no 'Y' cases, it automatically becomes `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(base_value = result[flag == 'Y'][1],
      percentage_change = 100 *(result - base_value)/base_value) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 6
      id result flag  col_1 base_value percentage_change
   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> <chr>      <dbl>             <dbl>
 1     1     NA ""    a             13              NA  
 2     1     33 ""    b             13             154. 
 3     1     13 "Y"   c             13               0  
 4     1     44 ""    d             13             238. 
 5     2     23 "Y"   e             23               0  
 6     2     44 ""    f             23              91.3
 7     2     52 ""    g             23             126. 
 8     2     11 ""    h             23             -52.2
 9     3     NA ""    i             NA              NA  
10     3     NA ""    j             NA              NA
```